# LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types - How to fix without ToList() call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetQueryable()
{
    var results = _repository.Table;
    if (typeof(IStoreScopedEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        results = results.Where(e => ((IStoreScopedEntity)e).Stores.Select(s => s.Id).Contains(EngineContext.Current.StoreScopeId));
    }
    return results;
}
```

and am getting the error in the post title. I know I could call `ToList()` on the entities so they are retrieved from the database and then cast but I'd like to avoid bring back data from the database when I don't need it.

Is there any way I can get this to work without loading the entire list of items from the database into memory and then selecting?

Comment: Why not `results.OfType<IStoreScopedEntity>().Where(...` ?

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, tried but got `Core.IStoreScopedEntity' is not a valid metadata type for type filtering operations. Type filtering is only valid on entity types and complex types.`

Comment: You should pass a type instead of an interface to `OfType`.

Comment: Ok, what type am I meant to be passing here? I know they are all of type `T` as it's a generic method so I don't really understand how using `OfType<T>` would help. I assume I'm missing something simple here ...

Comment: We should know more about your inheritance hierarchy and what is the purpose of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit tricky, but doable.

First we need a helper generic constrained function. Since from your definition looks like the `GetQueryable` function is part of a generic class, let put the helper function in a separate class

```
public static class StoreScopedEntity
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> IdPredicate<T>(int id)
        where T : IStoreScopedEntity
    {
        return e => e.Stores.Select(s => s.Id).Contains(id); 
    } 
}
```

I assume `StoreScopeId` is of type `int`, but you can change it to actual type if it's different.

Now the only remaining is how to call that function. There are several ways of doing that, here I'll use pure reflection

```
public IQueryable<T> GetQueryable()
{
    var results = _repository.Table;
    if (typeof(IStoreScopedEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        results = results.Where((Expression<Func<T, bool>>)
            typeof(StoreScopedEntity)
            .GetMethod("IdPredicate", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T))
            .Invoke(null, new object[] { EngineContext.Current.StoreScopeId }));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, I'll take a look at the implementation when I'm back in the code. What's the overhead going to be like using reflection for something like this?

Comment: Well, I guess you are not calling this function million times per second. I don't expect performance problems, but if you have some concerns, the reflection part can be moved in your class static constructor, this will happen only once. Let me know if you need example of such optimization.